# unable to re-open a window on pyqt5 pyqtlet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a basic GUI window, created with pyqt5 package, that contain a button that once clicked opens a map window thanks to Python's pyqtlet package.

My program does open the map window on first click, but here my issue:

**If I close the map window and click again on the button it only show me a white window.**

### SOURCE CODE

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from pyqtlet import L, MapWidget


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # set window title
        self.setWindowTitle('Windowtitle')

        # set layout
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # create button to show the map
        self.show_map_button = QPushButton('Show Map')
        self.show_map_button.clicked.connect(self.show_map)

        # add button to layout
        self.layout.addWidget(self.show_map_button, 0, 1)

        # show layout
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.my_map = None

    def show_map(self):
        # create map window instance
        self.my_map = MapWindow()

class MapWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # Setting up the widgets and layout
        super().__init__()
        self.mapWidget = MapWidget()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mapWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Working with the maps with pyqtlet
        self.map = L.map(self.mapWidget)
        self.map.setView([12.97, 77.59], 10)
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(self.map)
        self.marker = L.marker([12.934056, 77.610029])
        self.marker.bindPopup('Maps are a treasure.')
        self.map.addLayer(self.marker)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()

    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> 1. I click the button for the first time (works as expected):

[image]

> 2. The second time I click it **doesn't work** as expected:

[image]

Please, can you help me find out where the issue is?

Comment: Please do not delete post but edit them because if you keep doing it you probably won't be able to ask questions

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to reopen the window but you are creating a new window but pyqtleft only allows you to register a "map" object. So if you want to reopen the window after the user closed it then check that if the object exists then just use the show method:

```py
def show_map(self):
    if self.my_map is None:
        # create map window instance
        self.my_map = MapWindow()
    else:
        self.my_map.show()
```